# php -v always returns php@5.6

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, homebrew, wsl-2

Installed php@5.6 and php@8.1 with brew. `php -v` shows php@5.6 after `brew link php@5.6 --force --overwrite` (normal).

Then, after using `brew unlink php@5.6` and `brew link php --force --overwrite` to switch to php@8.1, `php -v` **still** displays php@5.6.

In other words, I'm stuck with php@5.6 and cannot switch to php@8.1.

I know I edited a config file and added a line specifying php@5.6, but I can't remember which file it was.

***How can I switch to php@8.1?***

I'm using *brew* in *Ubuntu* via *WSL 2* under *Windows*. Thanks.

Comment: Brew on Ubuntu? _Why?_

Comment: Since you have multiple versions installed you need to set the default version. According to this link https://www.tecmint.com/install-different-php-versions-in-ubuntu/amp/ you need to run `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1` Also, you should be able to run the specific version directly. ie `php8.1 -v`

Comment: @MarshallC, still shows PHP 5.6.40.

Comment: @arkascha, installation guide of the project was written for macOS. I mainly followed the guide. Also, PHP link and unlink were working perfectly fine before I edited that config file. _Brew is not the culprit here._

Comment: I never said that brew won't work. But it adds a ton of overhead compared to simply using the perfectly fine working native package management. By using brew you double that layer, risking conflicts and you stuff your system with parallel installations.

Comment: @arkascha I understand. But that is out of scope for this question for i could switch between php versions perfectly fine before editing this config file i still haven't found.

Comment: As you like ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try splitting the command into two like so

```
 brew unlink php && brew link --overwrite --force php@8.1
```

The command above works for me.

Ref: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-monterey-apache-multiple-php-versions

Comment: Still shows 'PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 16:59:52)'

Comment: Which version of MacOS are you using?

Comment: _Just updated OP;_  running WSL 2 for Windows, in a Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Can you echo out the phpinfo() to see if the CLI is printing out the right version?

Comment: _Attempting to launch the server requiring php version 8.0+ 
:_
PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 5.6.40. in /home/user/projects/project-name/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 25